# 500 Internal Server Error when using .htaccess with RewriteEngine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am on the shared host [Bounceweb](http://bounceweb.com) and I am trying to add some rewrite rules to make my links look prettier.

One of these rules is to make the url: `http://mysite.com/upload` point to: `http://mysite.com/upload.php`. I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^upload$ upload.php
```

but all it's giving me is a 500 Internal Server Error. I looked at my logs and this comes up a lot:

```
[alert] [client 81.179.29.185] /home/minecraf/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Does this mean my host doesn't support .htaccess? Pretty lame if they don't. I've already tried changing the permissions of .htaccess to 777 and it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`\xef\xbb\xbf` are three invisible junk characters (at least from Apache's perspective) called the Unicode BOM, or byte order mark. Apache thinks that those characters are part of the command that follows right after. This is what you see in the log, though the characters are escaped so they're visible to the naked eye. `\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine`

In your editor, especially if your editor is Notepad, make sure you're saving your file without a BOM. This should be selectable in the save as dialog or elsewhere.

Comment: ahhh I see. I used my FTP clients own editor to do the .htaccess, which is probably why this happened. Just did it with notepad and everything is fine now, thanks :)

Comment: you just saved my life! I couldn't figure out why my rewrite constantly gave a 500 error :) Saved it as Asci and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 28):

It might be the `mod_rewrite` module is not loaded.

**Windows xampp** : Open `xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and uncomment mod_rewrite module.
**Windows wamp** : Open `wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.x.x/conf/httpd.conf` and uncomment mod_rewrite module.
**Ubuntu** : `a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart`
or `cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load`

Then reload apache

Answer (score 11):

To remove the BOM in unix use vi and below command

: set nobomb

: wq

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
a2enmod rewrite    
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

rewriterule ^upload$ upload.php

</IfModule>
```

try this.

Comment: Nope, still coming up with a 500 error. Error log says: `[alert] [client 81.179.29.185] /home/minecraf/public_html/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save your .htaccess file with UTF-8 encoding (without BOM) and upload.
Recommended to use Notepad++. (in my case that helped).

atb