# Error with my htaccess. What's wrong?

Tags: php, .htaccess, permalinks

The CMS is OK because all works when I use that on localhost (WAMP) but when I uploaded on FTP I see 500 Internal Server Error. What is wrong? I tried to think of everything. I so sorry for my English.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
#######################################

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

order allow,deny
deny from 65.18.169.227
allow from all

<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
    php_value register_globals off
    php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
    php_value default_charset iso-8859-1
</ifModule>
########################################

<ifModule mod_rewrite>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user_profile=$1
RewriteRule ^widget/(.*)$ ./widget.php?user_widget=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^delete/(.*)$ ./ajax.php?cmd=delete_qa&del_id=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^site/terms ./terms.php
RewriteRule ^site/privacy ./privacy.php
RewriteRule ^ajax/ask ./ajax.php?cmd=ask
RewriteRule ^ajax/checkusername ./ajax.php?cmd=check_name
RewriteRule ^ajax/answer ./ajax.php?cmd=answer_qa
RewriteRule ^account/signup ./signup.php
RewriteRule ^account/login ./login.php
RewriteRule ^account/inbox ./inbox.php
RewriteRule ^account/forgotpassword ./forgotpassword.php
RewriteRule ^account/settings ./account_settings.php
RewriteRule ^account/profile ./account_profile.php
RewriteRule ^account/photo ./account_photo.php
RewriteRule ^account/design ./account_design.php
RewriteRule ^account/widget ./account_widget.php
RewriteRule ^account/disable ./account_disable.php
RewriteRule ^site/disabled ./disabled.php
RewriteRule ^site/error ./error.php
RewriteRule ^search/profiles ./search.php
RewriteRule ^account/logout ./logout.php
RewriteRule ^site/complete ./logout-complete.php
RewriteRule ^site/maintenance ./maintenance.php

#####################################

# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_ssl.c>
#SSLVerifyClient    optional_no_ca
#SSLVerifyDepth 5
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
#SSLRequireSSL

</ifModule>
```

This is my logs:

```
[Sat Oct 26 02:21:55 2013] [alert] [client 178.36.102.110] /home/drolepl/domains/domena.pl/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfErrorDocument', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
```

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373334/500-internal-server-error-when-using-htaccess-with-rewriteengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text editor is adding a Unicode byte order mark (BOM), as Jake Worrell pointed out.  You should be able to save the file without the BOM by changing a setting in your text editor.