# .htaccess rewritebase when in subdirectory on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

As I am trying to transfer my website from localhost to a test domain on our server, I need to adjust my htaccess, since it refers on the localhost to a different folder. I am transfering it to `test.mydomain.com/jellyweb/` yet whenever I adjust the rewritebase to match it, the site gives me a 500 error.

```
    php_flag display_errors on

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^195\.238\.74\.8 
#   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jellyfishwebdesign.nl/$1 [R=301,L]  
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
#   RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /test/jellyweb/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?p=$1&sp=$2&t=$3 [L]
```

The folder layout is `public_html/test/jellyweb`

I am not sure how get the rewritebase link correctly in this case, cause even when i just do `RewriteBase /jellyweb/` it doesn't work. Am I overseeing something? Sorry, htaccess is not I am familair with really.

edit

this is the error it pops out.

`[Wed Jul 01 16:32:52 2015] [alert] [client 195.240.165.183] /home/jellyf1q/public_html/test/jellyweb/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

hmmm realizing now it may be in the rewriterule of the last line, but not sure what i do wrong.

Comment: The htacces file is in the root of the website so in the `/jellyweb/` folder, and i get the 500 on just the test site then (the original domain is unaffected, just on every link after `test/domainname.nl/jellyweb/`) when I do a check in the test folder, the subfolder jellyweb isn't showing then.

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what is exact error for 500 in browser?

Comment: updated the question with the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, thanks to this post.

[500 Internal Server Error when using .htaccess with RewriteEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373334/500-internal-server-error-when-using-htaccess-with-rewriteengine)

It seemed, since it was saved as UTF8, it added some bytes to it, apache couldn't read. I resaved the file in asci and removed the php command line, resulting it working again. Thanks for the help, @Anubhava