# add .html to url but results 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745490/rewrite-rule-to-add-html-extension) and bababa but sadly none of them can direct me how to debug.

I am trying to redirect below url
https://example.com/hello
to
https://example.com/hello.html

Here is how I did

***First***

vim `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, set `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory /var/www/>`

Now is

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

***Second***

`sudo service apache2 restart`

***Third***

Create `.htaccess` in `public_html` and below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html

</IfModule>
```

But still return 404 not found like below.

[image]

Any suggestion or any parts I am missing to config apache? Thanks

---

### ***------ANSWER------***

Missed the configuration for `mod_rewrite`. Can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429052/5737856)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `.html` at the end of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` which will aways cause a 404 since `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` represents full filesystem path not the URI path.

You should use this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

or even better:

```sh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi. I still get the 404 error. Please see my updated post. I uploaded an screenshot of what I get with the 404 error. Maybe the configuration as well?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: ohh. No 500 error is shown even i put some garbage text in .htaccess. That means something wrong in apache2.conf? Please see additional information from the post. Guess maybe something wrong in user account in apache

Comment: You have `AllowOverride All` inside `/var/www/`. Is this your `DocumentRoot` as well? And does `.htaccess` exist right there?

Comment: .htaccess is in ```/var/www/hello/public_html```. So, I should add ```<Directory /var/www/hello/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>``` in apache2.conf?

Comment: Yes and make sure `/var/www/hello/public_html` is set as `DocumentRoot` as well. After restarting Apache run that verification of 500 error again.

Comment: for ```/var/www/hello/public_html is set as DocumentRoot``` Do you mean to set it in ```/etc/apache2/sites-available/hello.conf```?

Comment: I see. I am not too :) Thanks a lot. Will try to figure it out

Comment: Not really. Will notice you and test your code after configured the Apache

Comment: Hi. Finally find out the reason. It is because I missed out the configuration for ```mod_rewrite```